# Next.js nginx doesn't update cache data after building

Tags: reactjs, nginx, caching, next.js

I have one website using next.js and nginx.

It's getting data from datocms.

My issue is that the site content doesn't update even though data updated in datocms and run yarn build command.
Here is screenshot of site request
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3sCw.png)

I checked the var/cache/nginx and cleared but it is still same.

My Next.js version is  ^13.4.9.

I want to get and display the updated content once build the website on the nginx server.